# Compatibility of named colors below iOS 11

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode11

I need to implement the dark mode in my iOS app which runs on iOS 8+. Also I have custom colors defined in color assets with RGB codes for both light and dark appearance.

The problem is named colors are not supported proir to iOS 11, but I can use only named colors to support both appearances - dark and light.

Is there any way to implement a backward compatibility?

Comment: “but I can use only named colors to support both appearances - dark and light.” Well _that_ isn’t true. It’s perfectly possible to support light/dark mode without using any asset catalog color sets. “Is there any way to implement a backward compatibility?” Light/dark mode exists only in iOS 13 so what would you like backward compatibility to consist of?

Comment: @matt You're right. I have more common issue - how to support light/dark mode on iOS 13 with compatibility with iOS 8? And have universal project resources (xibs, assets) to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it while using color assets. However you can create your own `ThemeManger` to handle the app's theme.

First create a `ThemeManager`. It's main purpose is to hold the `style` of the app.

```
class ThemeManager {

    static let shared: ThemeManager = ThemeManager()

    var style: ThemeStyle = .light 
}
```

Here `ThemeStyle` should be an enum containing your themes(light, dark etc.).

Create a `ThemeColor` class to handle your colors

```
class ThemeColor {
    var dark: UIColor = UIColor.clear
    var light: UIColor = UIColor.clear
    var asset: String = ""    

    func getColor(for theme: ThemeStyle = ThemeManager.shared.style) -> UIColor {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            if asset != "", let assetColor = UIColor(named: asset) {
                return assetColor
            }
        }
        if theme == .dark {
            return dark
        }

        return light
    }
}
```

You can use the `getColor` function to get required color. Notice that `ThemeColor` returns the `asset` color value for iOS 13. This is for changing the app's theme when user changes his/her preference from settings.

Example:

```
extension UIColor {
    class var backgroundColor: ThemeColor {
        let themeColor = ThemeColor()
        themeColor.light = UIColor.white
        themeColor.dark = UIColor.black
        themeColor.asset = "backgroundColor"

        return themeColor
    }
}

// Somewhere in your code set the backgroundColor of your view
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.backgroundColor.getColor()
```

- To make this work you need to update your `style` variable in `ThemeManger` based on user's preference for iOS 13 devices. You can do this by `traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?)` implementing this method in your `UIViewController` class.
- Just like the `backgroundColor` example you need to define all your colors which are effected by the theme change.
- Set the `style` value of your `ThemeManger` to your preferred `style` so that your app opens in it's default theme when not running on iOS 13.

**Edit**: If your users won't be able to change the app's theme on their own from within the app itself then you don't need the `light` and `dark` UIColor values in `ThemeColor`. Just define a `defaultColor` value and return it at the end of `getColor` function. This will allow your app to appear in it's default theme for devices running iOS 12 or lower.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Is there a way to use this method in storyboards and xibs too?

Comment: As far as I know you can't. The reason is that storyboards access your custom colors from `color assets`  but you won't be able to do it since `color assets` are supported after iOS 11.0 and later.

Comment: You can however use this method at `viewDidLoad` or `awakeFromNib` functions of your `UIViewController`, `UITableViewCell` etc.

Comment: `ThemeColor` seems much more suitable as an `enum`, as you don't have/want an initialiser.